# Android Fragment go back does doesn't work, setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar, pageviews

After showing ArticlesActivity view, I can not go back to mainActivity by pressing arrow.
 I have added setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and setHomeButtonEnabled(true)

Manifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".views.LoadingActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".views.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
....
```

mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Article>> articlesHomeList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        articlesHomeList = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Article>>) bundle.getSerializable("articlesHomeList");
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        ....
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Bundle bundleMyNews = new Bundle();
        bundleMyNews.putSerializable("articles", (Serializable) this.articlesHomeList.get(0));
        MyNewsFragment myNewsFragment = new MyNewsFragment();
        myNewsFragment.setArguments(bundleMyNews);

        Bundle bundleMyThemes = new Bundle();
        bundleMyThemes.putSerializable("articles", (Serializable) this.articlesHomeList.get(1));
        MyThemesFragment myThemesFragment = new MyThemesFragment();
        myThemesFragment.setArguments(bundleMyThemes);

        Bundle bundleAllNews = new Bundle();
        bundleAllNews.putSerializable("articles", (Serializable) this.articlesHomeList.get(2));
        AllNewsFragment allNewsFragment = new AllNewsFragment();
        allNewsFragment.setArguments(bundleAllNews);

        AdapterTabs adapter = new AdapterTabs(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(myThemesFragment, "My Themes");
        adapter.addFragment(myNewsFragment, "My News");
        adapter.addFragment(allNewsFragment, "All News");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }}
```

MyNewsFragment.java

```
public class MyNewsFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Article> articlesList;
    public ContentAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragment = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, co

    ntainer, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragment.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        //((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("----");

        /*View btnRefresh = container.findViewById(R.id.action_refresh);
            btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("--MyNewsFragment","btnSerach click");
            }
        });*/

        articlesList = (List<Article>) this.getArguments().getSerializable("articles");

        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(articlesList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        // Obtener el refreshLayout
        refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) fragment.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);

        // Seteamos los colores que se usarán a lo largo de la animación
        refreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
               R.color.co_colorAccent
        );

        // Iniciar la tarea asíncrona al revelar el indicador
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    //new HackingBackgroundTask().execute();
                    Log.d("--Refreshhh", "----");
                }
            }
        );

        return recyclerView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("--MyNewsFragment", "Onstart");
        //this.loadArticles();
    }

    private void loadArticles() {
        AppController appController = new AppController(getActivity());
        SettingsAppController settingsAppController = new SettingsAppController(getActivity());
        Auth auth = settingsAppController.getAuth();
        try {
            Log.d("------iniciandooo", "loadArticles");
            appController.getArticlesRequest(auth, new AppController.GetArticlesRequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void getArticlesResponse(ApiResponse response) {
                    if (response.getSuccess()) {
                        articlesList = response.getArticlesList();
                        Log.d("--MyThemesFragment", "Response get articles received");
                        setAdapter(new ContentAdapter(articlesList));
                    } else {
                        Log.e("--LoadingActivity", "Error " + response.getErrorCode() + ": " + response.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (ErrorServerException e) {
            Log.e("--ERRRRRRRRROR", e.getMessage().toString());
        }
        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(articlesList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    public ContentAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(ContentAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("Item selected", "fragment");
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        private List<Article> articles;

        public ContentAdapter(List<Article> articles) {
            this.articles = articles;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            try {
                if (articles.get(position).getImagePath() != "") {
                        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(articles.get(position).getImagePath()).error(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).into(holder.image);
                } else {
                        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).into(holder.image);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).into(holder.image);
                Log.e("--ContentAdapter", "onBindViewHolder  error image");
            }
            holder.title.setText(articles.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.time.setText(articles.get(position).getTime());
                holder.domain.setText(articles.get(position).getSource().getDomain());
            holder.article = articles.get(position);
            holder.position = position;
        }


        public void addArticles(List<Article> articles){
            //TODO
            articles.addAll(articles);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (this.articles != null)
                return this.articles.size();
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return articles.get(position).getId();
        }

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView time;
        public TextView domain;
        public Article article;
        public Integer position;

        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false));
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
            time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTime);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
            domain = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardDomain);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Title: " + article.getTitle(),
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    gotoArticleDetails(v.getContext(), article, position);
                }
            });
            title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Title: " + article.getTitle(),
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        gotoArticleDetails(v.getContext(), article, position);
                    }
                });
            }

        public void gotoArticleDetails(Context context, Article article, Integer position) {
            Log.d("--LoadingActivity", "gotoHomeActivity");
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ArticlesActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("article", article);
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

ArticlesActivity

```
public class ArticlesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Article article;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_articles);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        this.article = (Article) bundle.getSerializable("article");
        Integer position = (int) bundle.getInt("position");

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Set Collapsing Toolbar layout to the screen
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        // Set title of Detail page
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(article.getTitle());


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        try {
            if (article.getImagePath() != "") {
                Picasso.with(this).load(article.getImagePath()).error(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).into(image);
            } else {
                Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).into(image);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.placeholder_blue_sd).into(image);
            Log.e("--ArticlesActivity", "on create  error image");
        }

        TextView domain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.articleDomain);
        domain.setText(article.getSource().getDomain());
        TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.articleTime);
        time.setText(article.getTime());

        TextView secondTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondTitle);
        secondTitle.setText(article.getTitle());

        TextView body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body);
        body.setText(article.getBody());

        Button btnOpenWebView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpenWebView);
        btnOpenWebView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("article", getArticle());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    public Article getArticle() {
        return article;
    }

    public void setArticle(Article article) {
        this.article = article;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

You need to update your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".views.ArticlesActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:parentActivityName=".views.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".views.MainActivity" />
</acivity>
```

And override `onOptionsItemSelected` in your `ArticlesActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: @ Boban S. when I go back mainActivity I got:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.....views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
Line 68: articlesHomeList = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Article>>) bundle.getSerializable("articlesHomeList");

Comment: That is another problem. You need to initialize your `MainActivity` correctly.

Comment: Your `MainActivity` expects some extras in intent. But when you go back from `ArticlesActivity` with the up button it gets empty intent. You should handle that.

Comment: Thanks @Boban for your help